# How to handle 'undefined' error for dynamically changing deep nested objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a react based project using [formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) to handle the forms and [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) for writing validation schemas. Now I'm trying to validate a nested form where I just wanted to add a CSS class to the input if an error object at the respective index of the nested field is present in the errors array, which holds the error messages of input groups and the input is touched.
To be specific, this is the code which I need to refactor

```
className={"form-control " + (touched.representatives 
&& (errors.representatives 
&& (errors.representatives[index] 
&& (touched.representatives[index] 
&& (touched.representatives[index].name 
&& (errors.representatives[index].name ? 'is-invalid' : 'ivalid'))))))}
```

The errors object will be something like:

```
errors = {representatives: 
           [{name: "Name is required", email: "Email is required"}, 
            {name: "Name is required"}]}
```

The problem is that initially the errors object will be empty until the user touches the input. If the user adds another set of inputs by clicking the "add new" button, an errors object won't be present for that input until the user touches it, and it will then throw an error if I don't checked for its presence then.

I know I can write a function with `try` and `catch`, but since the errors are added and removed dynamically with every user's input, that won't work here. The code is working fine, but can someone suggest a better approach as I see this code is a bit ugly.

Comment: can you use library like lodash ?

Comment: Using prop-types https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types and default values might help you

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear what the code you've written is trying to achieve, but accessing deeply nested properties of objects is best done using a function like `get()` from [`lodash`](https://lodash.com).

So instead of:

```
const name = errors && errors.representatives && errors.representatives[index] && errors.representatives[index].name;
```

you can just do something like:

```
import { get } from 'lodash';
const name = get(errors, `representatives[${index}].name`);
```

which will handle any `undefined`s and not crash.

If you can't add lodash to your project for some reason *(although it would really be much better to use lodash, it's great and very field-hardened!)*, then I would just write a simple function to simulate it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But `representatives[${index}].name` might or might not exist based on what user enters in the input. If there are no errors in the input group, `errors.representatives[${index}]` will be an empty object. So, I'll need to call `get(errors, `representatives[${index}].name`);` everytime user changes the input, right?

Comment: yup! and if your test is whether there are any keys in `errors.representatives[${index}]` then you could use ``Object.keys(get(errors, `representatives[${index}]`, {})).length > 0``